# Command line argument option with number offset

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, argv, getopt, argc

I want to ensure that the option/ argument after -f is a number between 0-9. There must be 10 arguments, in total, in any order. The only condition is that -f must be followed by a digit.

```
/* Ensure that the -f option is included in the arguments
and it is preceeded by valid digit between 0 -9 */
int Crypto::offsetValidation( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < argc; i++ )
    {
        if(argv[i] == string("-f"))             
        {           
            cout << "offset" << endl;           
            return offset;
        }       
    }   

    cout << "Usage: -f is required for offset" << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Use `getopt()`, then check that what it points to with `optarg` is a single-digit number (`strlen(optarg) == 1 && isdigit(optarg[0])`).  Ad hoc argument parsing will get you into all sorts of ad hoc problems.

Comment: Awesome; thanks for the insight. 

How do I ensure that it is right after the " -f " option though...

Comment: `int opt; while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "f:")) != -1) { switch (opt) { case 'f': …play with optarg…; break; default: …usage error and exit…; break; } }` is the outline code.  You can't guarantee that you have `-f3` or whatever, but your original string compare would not have allowed that.  With `getopt()`, you're guaranteed that if you have `-f3` or `-f 3` on the command line, then `strcmp(optarg, "3") == 0`.  I'm blithely assuming you only have `-f` arguments; you'd need more code to handle the others, whatever they are.

Comment: Brilliant, There are several other arguments that are validated. This was giving me the most challenges. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transcribing comments into an answer*</sup>

Use [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html)
, then check that what it points to with `optarg` is a single-digit number (`strlen(optarg) == 1 && isdigit(optarg[0])`). Ad hoc argument parsing will get you into all sorts of ad hoc problems.

> How do I ensure that it is right after the " -f " option though…

You can write code similar to the following:

```
int opt;
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "f:")) != -1)
{
    switch (opt)
    {
    case 'f':
        if (strlen(optarg) == 1 && isdigit(optarg[0]))
            f_value = optarg[0] - '0';
        else
            err_exit("Invalid value '%s' for -f option", optarg);
        break;
    default:
        …usage error and exit…;
        break;
    }
}
```

You can't guarantee that you have `-f3` or whatever, but your original string compare would not have allowed that. With `getopt()`, you're guaranteed that if you have `-f3` or `-f 3` on the command line, then `strcmp(optarg, "3") == 0`. I'm blithely assuming you only have `-f` arguments; you'd need more code to handle the others, whatever they are.  You need to add the extra option letters to the string currently containing `"f:"`, and extra cases to the switch, and the variables to handle them.

I should also add that this is C code that can be compiled by C++ rather than 'real C++'.  There's a [Boost](http://boost.org/) library for parsing options in C++ that may be a better choice — if you're allowed to use Boost in your project.  There are also many other option parsers in general.  The GNU [`getopt_long()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt) is also widely used for long option name parsing (`--file name-of-file` etc).